# How do I lock text fields and images in place in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage, uitextfield

When I am designing the interface everything looks fine.But when I run the project some text fields move and get mixed with other text fields.Some images go down.How do I lock everything in place ,so that the gui is exactly the way I designed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi iOsBody there are some layout problem is bellow Tips you can set properly.

- in your issue you have use `UINavigationController` in every `viewController` but when you set XIB layout you can not add this 45px `UInavigationBar` space in XIB that's why you facing this issue.
- while you use this in ios6 You can also use AutoLayout but its some time getting Creshed in ios5 or bellow ios

So please check proparly x,y and also put calculate px of `UInavigationBar` or statusbar while create Interface.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Fix Property]

You can fix property of Textfield & image. So, it'll not move anywhere & stay at their own places.

Hopefully, it will help you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your view using AutoLayout functionality than uncheck it.
[image]

see the option `Use AutoLayout` in your main view .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1)this will help u auto size the components